# Displaying a session variable

Tags: php, html, session, variables

Can someone tell me why the variable is not being displayed in bold once I press submit? In essence what I am trying to do is ask the user on page 1, there name... then a few pages later display that name inside a hidden input form field, but I can't seem to get it working on the same page never mind a few pages later.

```
<body>
<strong>Test Form</strong>
<form action="" method"post">
<input type="text" name="picturenum"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>

<?php 

 // starting the session
 session_start();


 if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
 $_SESSION['picturenum'] = $_POST['picturenum'];
 } 
?> 

<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['picturenum'];?></strong>
</body>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: have you tried echoing $_POST['picturenum'] to see if it actually has data in it?

Comment: ^ This, and `$_POST['Submit']`.

Comment: Is your action of your form element empty in your local copy?

Comment: @crush - Empty `action` attribute = submit to current URL, it's a perfectly acceptable practice.

Comment: @Oshawott Well, he should actually omit the action attribute altogether, but w/e. Read for yourself: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-action and https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=14215#c1

Comment: Hi tried echoin picturenum and submit and nothing has came up

Comment: ugh i didn't even look at the form, there's no = sign as @claustrofob points out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

`<form action="" method"post">` Should probably be `<form action="" method="post">`

This is causing your form to submit as a GET request. That means your vars are in `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: 3 cheers for you good sir :) + thanks for explanation

Answer (score 2):

The session_start should be at the top of your scrip, before there is any output becouse it send the session headers to the browser. Try this:

```
<?php
 session_start();
?>
<body>
<strong>Test Form</strong>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="picturenum"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>

<?php 


 if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
 $_SESSION['picturenum'] = $_POST['picturenum'];
 } 
?> 

<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['picturenum'];?></strong>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi thanks I have tried this but it didn't work however it has appeared in the address bar when I press submit.

http://www..info/php/?picturenum=hi&Submit=Submit%21

Comment: @craigie2204 is method"post" the actual code or is it a typo, because it should be method="post" ?

Comment: Hi lex yes it was a typo.. rookie mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `<form action="" method"post">` to `<form action="somepage.php" method="post">`.

Note that you forgot the `=` after `method`.

If you want to submit the form to the page it's on, use `<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">`.

EDIT: Seems only the `=` was required to fix your script.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <strong>Test Form</strong>
  <form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="picturenum"/>
   <input type="submit" name="Sub" value="Submit" />
   </form>
  <?php 
  session_start();
  $_POST['picturenum'];
  $_SESSION['picturenum1'] = $_POST['picturenum'];
  $_SESSION['picturenum1'];
  ?>
  <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['picturenum1'];?></strong>
   </body>
   </html>
```